# Fire base queries compuestos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Hola amigos estoy aprendiendo a usar Firebase y quiero hacer un querie compuesto y veolverlo a mi vista, hasta ahora mis queries lo estoy haciendo asi

```
router.get('/tables',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('');
   db.ref('tables').once('value',(snapshot)=>{
    const data = snapshot.val();
    res.render('tables.hbs',{tables: data});
    });
 });
```

Estoy tratando de hacer esto

```
  let tablesOpenRef = db.ref('tables');
  let queryRef = tablesOpenRef.where('status', '==', 'open');
  console.log(queryRef)
```

> TypeError: tablesOpenRef.where is not a function
> pero me dice

Pero quiero agregarle un where `where stats == open` alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con:

```
db.ref('tables').orderByChild('stats').equalTo('open').once('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    res.render('tables.hbs', {
        tables: data
    });
});
```

Comment: el rey :3 muchas gracias amigo, aunque se me hace muy raro estaba sacando eso de la doc oficial https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es